# Truncate Django CMS Placeholder

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-cms

I'm creating my own Django CMS blog plugin. I'm using a placeholder to hold the full content of the blog entry and I'm trying to figure out how to automatically create an excerpt from this placeholder.

If it were simply a text field I know I could use "|truncatechars:15" in the template, but I don't know how to do this for a placeholder.

Is there something I can use in the template or in the 'views.py' in order to truncate the placeholder?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you've seen, you can't truncate a placeholder, as a placeholder's job is simply to render content plugins that are added to it.

Your only viable option is to truncate the field in the render template of the plugin, or to add a separate field on your model that can store the truncated text. Such a field could be populated automatically using a `post_save` signal handler.

Answer (score 0):

The way I prefer when I can't use django truncatechars, is to use CSS to resolve this problem.

Let's say that after rendering your placeholder you will have something like this:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div class="text">Your content from placeholder</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

To your CSS add this:

```
div.text {
    width: 120px;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space:nowrap;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

Final result will look like this:

> Your content fro...